# why am getting couldn't load image in latest versions?

Tags: android

when picking image from gallery and making crop for it then it is going to be cropped but my main issue is that when am picking google photos it is unable to crop and showing Toast message like "couldn't load image". Please help me where am doing wrong.[image]
[image]

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
            {
                Log.e("Came", "onActivityResult")
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
                System.out.println("onActivityResulty===>" + data.toString() + "@@@@@" + resultCode + "#######" + requestCode)
                if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_GALLERY_IMAGE && null != data) {
                    mImageCaptureUri = data.data
                    try {

                        cropImage(mImageCaptureUri, output_pic, "square")
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    } catch (e: OutOfMemoryError) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }



                } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
                    try {

                        cropImage(mImageCaptureUri, output_pic, "square")
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    } catch (e: OutOfMemoryError) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                        System.out.println("OnActivity_Catch_Error===>" + e)
                    }

                }else if (requestCode == 1890) {


                    croppingImage()

                }}
```

https://www.android-examples.com/android-image-cropping-example-tutorial-pick-gallery-camera/

Answer (score 1):

That happens because picking an image from the camera and from the gallery don't return the same result, you have to check which one the user has chosen by looking at the intent; you can do it this way.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == mRequestCode) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                boolean isCamera = true;
                if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                    String action = data.getAction();
                    isCamera = MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.equals(action);
                }

                try {
                    Uri uriFileSrc = isCamera ? mOutputFileUri : data.getData();

                    //Do what do you need with the Uri

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, R.string.error_creating_file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } 
        }
}
```

Comment: hi vasanths294, Please once check my code.let me know where am doing mistake.